# StandardOutput ReadToEnd when process pauses by default

Tags: c#, process, console, wrapper

I must have looked through hundreds of articles related to the StandardOutput ReadtoEnd halting but none of them seem to answer my specific question.

The scenario I have is that I'm creating a wrapper for a 3rd party console app to be used in my ASP.NET MVC application. I start the process, pass it an input string (which is a dot file in string format) and the app returns a file (pdf in this case).

The file is placed into the stdout (according to the docs) however I don't seem to be able to read the data out.

When I run the console app manually, I receive the file as text in the output window but the program never really "exits". I have to CTRL+C to end the process.

I'm guessing this is why my calls to

```
process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Just hang?

Can anyone shed a bit of light into what I'm doing wrong. I'd like to return the file that's received in the output as a `byte[]` from my method call.

Thanks and appologies if it seems like this is a duplicate.

Comment: Did you process.RedirectStandardOutput = true; and to be sure check if the Console App. is outputing the STDOut to StandardError Stream .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `ReadToEnd()` returns a string. That's no good idea, if the data is binary
2. `ReadToEnd()` doesn't return, because the program never exits

Because of this, try reading the underlying stream (`process.StandardOutput.BaseStream`) with the more low level stream methods like [`Stream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) and detect yourself when the program finished sending its data.

Comment: Daniel, that's really helpful thanks. I have another question that's probably very basic. How do I know the array size of the byte[] basesd on the stream or is that not very important? Right now I'm passing in a buffer byte[10000] knowing that my output is actually about 8000.

Comment: If the buffer is to small, just call Read repeatedly. See the sample in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Calling Read the second time just seems to hang, but anyway, that's a seperate question. Thanks again for your help mate, much appreciated.

Comment: @Jamie: Yes, you have a problem with your 3rd party app. It should exit after it finished its work.

Comment: closing the input stream before reading the output seems to do the trick.